# Adding a caption to a div that already contains content

Tags: html, css

I have a small slider within a 200px by 200px div. However what I would really love is to have a 100px by 20px caption box in the top right hand corner with a colored background and one word inside it. The problem is, as I already have content in the box (the slider), if I try to add the caption div it does not sit over the top of the existing content, it instead distorts the size of the 200px by 200px div.

***HTML***

```
<div class="trigger">
    <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent static">
        <div class="slider2">
            <img src="client9.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
            <img src="client10.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
            <img src="client11.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
            <img src="client2.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.trigger {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.static {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #CCCCB2;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Add to CSS

```
.slider2 { position: relative; }

.caption-box {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width:100px;
  background-color: red; // change to suit
  color: #fff; // change to suit
}
```

Your HTML changed:

```
<div class="caption-box">Caption</div><!-- added this -->
<div class="slider2">
        <img src="client9.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
        <img src="client10.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
        <img src="client11.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
        <img src="client2.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Darren thanks for your help, this works but because it is within the slider2 div it is treated as if it is the first slide in the slider so disappears

Comment: Try it now, I've amended the answer - should be fine because `.static` is already positoned relative - simple move the new caption-box to before the slider

Comment: Thanks @Darren Sweeney Ill give you the props for this but could you just paste in comments the position:relative code? as it worked better with that in :)

Comment: Added it back in to the answer