# Adding A Div Caption To Divs Containing Sliders (Follow Up On Previous Q)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have a grid layout made up of image sliders and text slider with square divs. [I have just asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29559165/adding-a-caption-to-a-div-that-already-contains-content) of how to add captions to these squares within the grid. Now I can do this nicely when the div contains a text slider. However when I try to apply the same caption to divs containing the image slider it does not work, could somebody please show me how I can do this.

***CSS FOR DIVS***

```
.slider2 { position: relative; }

.caption-box {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
height: 20px;
width:100px;
background-color: red; // change to suit
color: #fff; // change to suit
}
.trigger {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
}

.static {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #CCCCB2;
border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

***BELOW IS THE HTML CODE OF THE TEXT SLIDER DIV WHERE THE CAPTION DIV WORKS WELL***

```
    <div class="trigger">
        <div class="slider2">
<div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: #CCCCB2; border-radius: 5px; height: 200px; width: 200px; color: #CCC;" class="just_text"><div class="caption-box">Monthly Plan</div>As part of our budget graphic design service we also offer a money saving monthly advertising schedule option. Whether it be for 6, 9 or 12 months we will remove all stress of advertising from your office leaving you to concentrate on your customers.    </div>
<div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: #CCCCB2; border-radius: 5px; height: 200px; width: 200px; color: #CCC;" class="just_text"><div class="caption-box">Web Updates</div>Our website design service also includes a money saving update scheme. For a monthly fee you can have updates to keep your website fresh and dynamic. No other company can offer this service.</div>
 </div>
    </div>
```

***BELOW IS THE HTML CODE OF THE IMAGE SLIDER WHERE I CAN NOT GET THE CAPTION DIV TO WORK***

```
  <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent static"><div class="slider2">
<img src="client9.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
<img src="client10.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
<img src="client11.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
<img src="client2.jpg" height="200" width="200" />
</div></div>
    </div>
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('.slider').sss({
slideShow : true, // Set to false to prevent SSS from automatically animating.
startOn : 0, // Slide to display first. Uses array notation (0 = first slide).
transition : 400, // Length (in milliseconds) of the fade transition.
speed : 20000, // Slideshow speed in milliseconds.
showNav : true // Set to false to hide navigation arrows.
});
$('.slider2').sss({
 slideShow : true, // Set to false to prevent SSS from automatically animating.
 startOn : 0, // Slide to display first. Uses array notation (0 = first slide).
 transition : 400, // Length (in milliseconds) of the fade transition.
 speed : 10000, // Slideshow speed in milliseconds.
 arrows : false // Set to false to hide navigation arrows.
 });
 });
 </script>
```

***CSS THAT JAVASCRIPT LINKS TO CALLED SSS.CSS***

```
.sss {
height: 0;
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
position: relative;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
}

.ssslide {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
}

.ssslide img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
display: block;
}

.sssnext, .sssprev {
width: 25px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
background: url('images/arr.png') no-repeat;
}

.sssprev {
left: 3%;
background-position: 0 50%;
}

.sssnext {
right: 3%;
background-position: -26px 50%;
}

.sssprev:hover, .sssnext:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}.row .col .trigger .slider2 .just_text {
color: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: You could improve any HTML/JS related question by leaving a small testable chunk inside http://www.jsfiddle.net or similar service.

Comment: @DanielFath Ok thanks for the advice, I shall do that when I get a chance. Could you help though it seems to be because the text in the text slider is contained by Divs it makes it work, but the images in the slider are not in divs. I have tried adding divs to the images with no joy but I might be laying it out wrong...I tried this... <div><img src="client9.jpg" height="200" width="200" /><div class="caption-box">Monthly Plan</div></div> but it didn't work so any modification to this would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code for the images is incomplete, and had to create my own version to be able to replicate the issue. But once that was done, the problem was easy to find. You can see it working on this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbrcbhxw/2/ (I took the liberty of cleaning it a bit so it was easier to read).

The problem is that `.static` has a `font-size:0` that makes the text invisible. Remove it (or don't wrap the div with the images with it), and the problem will be solved.

```
.static {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    /* font-size: 0; */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #CCCCB2;
    border-radius: 5px; 
}
```

The text version isn't wrapped around that `.static`, so that's why it was displayed correctly and didn't have the problem.

Comment: this works great on its own however when I implement it on the page it clashes with my javascript for some reason... javascript in question :(

Comment: Update the question to also add the real code for the images slider, and also include information about the slider. Right now it's not really useful: what is `.sss()`? what plug-in are you using?

Comment: shall i link to the actual page so you can see the actual page?

Comment: You can, but it would be more helpful if you put the information and the code in the question too. Links change and break, and what is an error now, won't be an error later. If someone finds this question in the future, the link  won't be helpful.

Comment: Also, removing the `font-size:0` shouldn't clash with your JavaScript. Was the JavaScript working before? If you put the `font-size:0` back, does your JavaScript work?

Comment: That is a totally unrelated issue. Add `z-index:1` to the `.caption-box` styles and the problem will be solved